# Can tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm calculate 2-D convolutional batch normalization as in the paper?

Tags: tensorflow, batch-normalization

As described in the original paper of batch normalization, batch normalization on 1-D feature (for example, from a fully connected layer) and that on 2-D feature (for example, from a convolutional layer) are different in a nontrivial way.

The tensorflow library provided an easy way to batch normalize with 1-D feature but I'm not sure if it is the same case for 2-D. The tool is `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm`.

I don't fully understand this method but can we apply this method for 2-D batch normalization?

I saw some people use it on 2-D feature map (with multiple channels): example 1 ([link 1](https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow/blob/master/ops.py#L29), [link 2](https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow/blob/master/model.py#L329)).

[Source page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b826b79718e3e93148c3545e7aa3f90891744cc0/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L100)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the usage of batch_normalization [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/resnet/resnet_model.py#L149) or search for the usage of `fused_bn` after Tensorflow 1.0.